# Pyspark find where the column is equal to empy list: .where('column = []')

Tags: python, java, sql, pyspark

`.where('column = []')`

This operation throws following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList []`

How to workaround this error to find empty lists in my column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. This will filter out the empty list in dataframe for pyspark.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
df.filter(sf.size('column_with_lists') > 0)
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `.where("column = '[]'")`.

`.withColumn("n", col("n").cast("string")).where(" n = '[]' ")`

```
sd2 = spark.createDataFrame((
  (1, "asf", [1, 2, 3]),
  (2, "2143", []),
  (4, "f8934y", [4, 7, 9])
), "lb int, st string, n array<int>")
print(sd2.dtypes)

sd2.where(" size(n) = 0").show()
sd2.withColumn("n", col("n").cast("string")).where(" n = '[]' ").show()

# [('lb', 'int'), ('st', 'string'), ('n', 'array<int>')]

# +---+----+---+
# | lb|  st|  n|
# +---+----+---+
# |  2|2143| []|
# +---+----+---+

# +---+----+---+
# | lb|  st|  n|
# +---+----+---+
# |  2|2143| []|
# +---+----+---+
```

Comment: have you tried using this in a sample data/code? it shouldn't work as the `column` field is an `ArrayType()` field.

Comment: It throws data type mismatch error: ```AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`divs` = '[]')' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`divs` = '[]')' (array<string> and string).; line 1 pos 0;```